# Duplicate class error from conflicting WebRTC library in React Native app

Tags: android, react-native, webrtc, sinch, voximplant

I've been looking workaround for the past few days but no avail. I'm using Voximplant only for instant messaging (IM) and wanted to use Sinch for VOIP calls to the other app. As Sinch IM doesn't fit our use case so we used Voximplant for the messaging which I first implemented.

Now I couldn't build with `react-native-sinch-voip` due to Voximplant SDK also contains VOIP functions, causing both libraries to conflict in `WebRTC` classes during build.

I managed to solve the conflict in iOS by renaming the CallManager class name but unable to resolve for Android.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class org.webrtc.AddIceObserver found in modules jetified-sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c-runtime (sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c.aar) and jetified-voximplant-sdk-2.27.0-runtime (com.voximplant:voximplant-sdk:2.27.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.AndroidVideoDecoder found in modules jetified-sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c-runtime (sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c.aar) and jetified-voximplant-sdk-2.27.0-runtime (com.voximplant:voximplant-sdk:2.27.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.AndroidVideoDecoder$1 found in modules jetified-sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c-runtime (sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c.aar) and jetified-voximplant-sdk-2.27.0-runtime (com.voximplant:voximplant-sdk:2.27.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.AndroidVideoDecoder$DecodedTextureMetadata found in modules jetified-sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c-runtime (sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c.aar) and jetified-voximplant-sdk-2.27.0-runtime (com.voximplant:voximplant-sdk:2.27.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.AndroidVideoDecoder$FrameInfo found in modules jetified-sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c-runtime (sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c.aar) and jetified-voximplant-sdk-2.27.0-runtime (com.voximplant:voximplant-sdk:2.27.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.AudioDecoderFactoryFactory found in modules jetified-sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c-runtime (sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c.aar) and jetified-voximplant-sdk-2.27.0-runtime (com.voximplant:voximplant-sdk:2.27.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.AudioEncoderFactoryFactory found in modules jetified-sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c-runtime (sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c.aar) and jetified-voximplant-sdk-2.27.0-runtime (com.voximplant:voximplant-sdk:2.27.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.AudioProcessingFactory found in modules jetified-sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c-runtime (sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c.aar) and jetified-voximplant-sdk-2.27.0-runtime (com.voximplant:voximplant-sdk:2.27.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.AudioSource found in modules jetified-sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c-runtime (sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c.aar) and jetified-voximplant-sdk-2.27.0-runtime (com.voximplant:voximplant-sdk:2.27.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.AudioTrack found in modules jetified-sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c-runtime (sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c.aar) and jetified-voximplant-sdk-2.27.0-runtime (com.voximplant:voximplant-sdk:2.27.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.BaseBitrateAdjuster found in modules jetified-sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c-runtime (sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c.aar) and jetified-voximplant-sdk-2.27.0-runtime (com.voximplant:voximplant-sdk:2.27.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.BitrateAdjuster found in modules jetified-sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c-runtime (sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c.aar) and jetified-voximplant-sdk-2.27.0-runtime (com.voximplant:voximplant-sdk:2.27.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.BuiltinAudioDecoderFactoryFactory found in modules jetified-sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c-runtime (sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c.aar) and jetified-voximplant-sdk-2.27.0-runtime (com.voximplant:voximplant-sdk:2.27.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.BuiltinAudioEncoderFactoryFactory found in modules jetified-sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c-runtime (sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c.aar) and jetified-voximplant-sdk-2.27.0-runtime (com.voximplant:voximplant-sdk:2.27.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.CallSessionFileRotatingLogSink found in modules jetified-sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c-runtime (sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c.aar) and jetified-voximplant-sdk-2.27.0-runtime (com.voximplant:voximplant-sdk:2.27.0)
...
```

I've tried several solution suggested, adding below code to `app/build.gradle` but couldn't get it work. Not sure if I'm using the right syntax as well. I'm not familiar with native Android, hence seeking for help.

```
implementation(project(':react-native-voximplant')){
    exclude group: 'com.voximplant', module:'org.webrtc.*'
}
```

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'org.webrtc.AndroidVideoDecoder'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to use Voximplant React Native SDK with other SDKs based on WebRTC. Voximplant SDK is based on specific version of WebRTC library with extra patches and excluding WebRTC native library from Voximplant Android SDK will lead to undefined behavior.

We are currently working on a major update for Voximplant SDK that will allow to use Voximplant messaging API without WebRTC dependency, however it takes several months to complete this version.